# Rails TimeWithZone doesn't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-6

I've been having a terrible time with 2 times that are saying it's not equal

```
# returns TRUE before persisted, but when retrieved from postgres it's FALSE
end_date == end_date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day
```

Your immediate thought is probably `usec` however I have checked that many times already, and both are `999999`:

```
[21] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.usec
=> 999999
[22] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day.usec
=> 999999
[23] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.to_i
=> 1580533199
[24] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day.to_i
=> 1580533199
[25] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
[26] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
[33] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.iso8601
=> "2020-02-01T04:59:59Z"
[34] pry(#<Lease>)> end_date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day.utc.iso8601
=> "2020-02-01T04:59:59Z"
```

This is driving me insane, I don't know what else to check...

**Edit:** it appears `nsec` is what is different. How the heck am I supposed to account for this? How do I truncate nanoseconds to a certain precision (6). Unless there's a better way to handle this when my times involve the 'end of the month' (the end of some term)

Comment: Why do you need the end of a time period? To do a comparison using `<=`? If so, you could do `< beginning_of_next_period` instead.

Comment: It's the period of a lease @fphilipe so it seems weird to store the beginning day of the day thats not actually in the lease. it means when i also want to show lease dates i will have to subtract one second from all of it.

Comment: I’d highly recommend using inclusive start and exclusive ends. It’s easier. Maybe this convinces you: http://qedcode.com/content/exclusive-end-dates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a model is saved to the DB those timestamps are stored in a type `timestamp without time zone` that [has microsecond resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html). When you have nanosecond precision in your time, it'll be truncated.

To fix it, you could try to:

- approximate a date with `round` to full microseconds:

```
1.day.ago.round(6).nsec
#=> 158812000
1.day.ago.round(6)
#=> Wed, 28 Aug 2019 03:21:51 EDT -04:00
```

- store the beginning of the next day

I'm aware that those are not the perfect solutions, can't think about a better one now.

Comment: I see, so what about when I'm comparing `Time.zone.now` which will have 9 figures vs database stuff which will have 6?